# Determine variable from Makefile in Fortran

Tags: macros, fortran, c-preprocessor

I want to align my data with `!DIR$ ATTRIBUTES ALIGN:NBYTE::X` where `NBYTE` is defined at compilation time. 
I am currently at the top of every source file have

```
 #ifndef NBYTE
  #define NBYTE 64
 #endif
```

However, I don't if I can define this only once I use the `NBYTE` variable everywhere. 
So my two questions are:

1. Is it possible to define the macro only once and use it everywhere without including a file or the macro in each source file?
2. Can I define the variable in the Makefile and use it in my Fortran code?

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Comment: Fortran Intel compiler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most compilers allow you to preprocess your source using a C-type preprocessor. Simultaneously, they allow you to pass preprocessor macros via command line of the compiler. In `gfortran` you can use the following syntax:

> **`-Dname=definition`:** The contents of the definition are tokenized and processed as if they appeared during translation phase three in a `#define` directive.  In particular, the definition will be truncated by embedded newline characters.

Comment: So if I say -DNBYTE=64 and add that flag while compiling the code, that will be it

Comment: @A2LBK For [`ifort`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-using-fortran-preprocessor-options) it is the same syntax

Comment: @A2LBK yes, but you need to make sure your code is beeing preprocessed.

Comment: Yes, I am doing this with the -fpp flag. Many thanks !