# Is that possible to let Fortran source code detect compiler flags?

Tags: fortran, openmp, blas, intel-mkl, openblas

The question is inspired by [OpenMP with BLAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66296334/openmp-with-blas)

The motivation is, I want the Fortran source code to be flexible to the complier options related to serial/parallel BLAS. I may specify `-mkl=parallel` for `mkl` or `USE_OPENMP=1` for `lopenblas` in the `Makefile`.
I may do `make ifort` or `make gfortran` or `make blah blah` to switch the libaries in the `Makefile`.
But,

a) If I use `-mkl=parallel` in the `Makefile`, I need to set `call mkl_set_num_threads(numthreads)`  in the source code,

b) If I use `OpenBLAS` with `USE_OPENMP=1`, I may need `openblas_set_num_threads(num_threads)` in the source code
[https://rdrr.io/github/wrathematics/openblasctl/man/openblas_set_num_threads.html#:~:text=threads%20to%20use.-,Details,t%20simply%20call%20R%27s%20Sys](https://rdrr.io/github/wrathematics/openblasctl/man/openblas_set_num_threads.html#:%7E:text=threads%20to%20use.-,Details,t%20simply%20call%20R%27s%20Sys).

c) for the time being if there is only `lblas` and/or with `-mkl=sequential`, I have to manually configurate `dgemm` threads (as kind of block decomposition), regardless `OMP_NUM_THREADS`. That's ok, but I need to use `if` to control the source code goes in that way, if the source code has lines for a) and b)

The manually programming `dgemm` threads in c) is somehow universal. When I would like to exploit parallel blas from libraries, things can be complicated it seems such that I don't know how to switch in source code regarding the compiler options.

Addition, `OMP_NUM_THREADS` from enviroment file, `.bashrc`, is not preferable. (Sorry I should have mentioned this point earlier) The source code read an input file which specify the number of cores being used, and use `omp_set_num_thread` to set the targeted number of cores, than from the enviroment file.

Addition2, from my test on `MKL`, `OMP_NUM_THREADS` cannot surpress `call mkl_set_num_threads`. Namely, I have to specify `call mkl_set_num_threads` to work with `-mkl=parallel` flag.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just set the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS`? If not you'll probably need some form of preprocessing.

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55219012/determine-variable-from-makefile-in-fortran) has some information on passing variables from a makefile to the Fortran preprocessor.

Comment: Agree with @IanBush: most modern BLAS libraries obey the OpenMP environment variables. It is in general not necessary to set the number of threads in the source.

Comment: About the only gotcha with the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` approach I've had to deal with is the stupid default most implementations have of using all the cores when the variable is *not* set. In that case you can use `get_environment_variable` to check for `OMP_NUM_THREADS` and if it isn't there use `omp_set_num_threads` to set the default number of threads to a sensible value, i.e. 1 - all of which is potable.

Comment: I will check only use `omp_set_num_threads` without `mkl_set_num_threads` / `openblas_set_num_threads`. I think I tried at some stage and didn't remember the result. The thing is, for the time if I only use `lblas`, seems `lblas` does not support parallel BLAS, and I need to write `DGEMM` by specifying threads and the associated matrix dimensions; for `lopenblas`/`mkl`,  I can set auto parallel `DGEMM`. Thus, I still need some `ifndef` / `ifdef`

Comment: I really have no idea what you mean. Is it that you have your own openmp threaded BLAS if MKL or OPENBLAS are not available? If that is the case `OMP_NUM_THREADS` will be respected - use *that* as the primary way to set the number of threads you use, only use `omp_set_num_threads` if you are paranoid about the case when `OMP_NUM_THREADS` is not set i.e. most codes never bother about it. In summary if you use the environment variable it is almost always possible to write code that does *not* need preprocessing, irrespective of the BLAS implementation.

Comment: I agree with Ian, I do not see any need for preprocessing or alternative submodules and for calling all those set_ routines. Not from your description anyway. It may be necessary in some strange circumstances, but normally it is pointless. But your "seems lblas does not support parallel BLAS, and I need to write DGEMM by specifying threads and the associated matrix dimensions" is not very clear. `OMP_NUM_THREADS`, `MKL_NUM_THREADS` and `OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS` (check the manual for the exact names) should do it in normal circumstances.

Comment: Reading the number of threads from a configuration file is your deaign decisiin, but quite a strange one. It is quite inflexible. With environment variables you are not limited to.bashrc, you can change it freely for wvery executed command. Just use `export`, or indeed juat for the aingle execution use `OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 ./mycommand`. With config files you are setring traps for your users or at least make it inconvenient for them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least two approaches to this.

### Preprocessor variables

As explained in e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55219012/determine-variable-from-makefile-in-fortran) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233923/conditional-compilation-in-gfortran), among others, you can pass variables from a Makefile directly to an appropriate preprocessor.

For example, in the branches of the Makefile where you set `-mkl=parallel` you could also set `-DMKL_PARALLEL`. Then, in your source code you could have a block which looks something like

```
#ifdef MKL_PARALLEL
  call mkl_set_num_threads(numthreads)
#endif
```

Provided you compile your code with an appropriate preprocessor, this allows you to pass arbitrary information from your Makefile to your source code.

### Separate files

Instead of using a preprocessor, you can have multiple copies of the same file, each with a different set of options, and only compile the correct file for the project.

A slightly nicer way of doing this is to have one module file, which is always the same regardless of options, and multiple [submodules](https://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Submodules), each of which contains one set of options. This reduces the room for error arising from multiple files, and reduces compilation time if you need to change the options.